# Can you use combinatorics rather than a tree for a best of five match?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> The Chicago Cubs are playing a best-of-five-game series (the first team to win 3 games win the series and no other games are played) against the St. Louis Cardinals.  Let X denotes the total number of games played in the series. Assume that the Cubs win 59% of their games versus their arch rival Cardinals and that the probability of winning game is independent of other games.
>
> (a)  calculate the mean and standard deviation for X.

In this problem I think I understand how to calculate the mean and standard deviation, but first you have to calculate the total combinations of plays.  Is there a way using combinations or permutations to derive all possibilities rather than drawing a tree?

The tricky thing with this using combinatorics is that its a best of five.  So I don't see how to use permutations directly because as soon as you have 3 wins the series is over--meaning you'll over count if you don't take this into consideration.

I'd appreciate any feedback.  Thank you!

---

### k=3

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Loss} & \text{Win} & \text{Combinations}\\
\hline
3 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 3 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$
Total Combinations = 8

### k=4

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Loss} & \text{Win} & \text{Combinations}\\
\hline
1 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 6\\
3 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

**Here have to subtract 1 from total combinations because cannot have WWWL.

Total combinations = 15-1 = 14

### k=5

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Loss} & \text{Win} & \text{Combinations}\\
\hline
2 & 3 & 10\\
3 & 2 & 10\\
4 & 1 & 5\\
5 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

**Here have to subtract from total combinations because cannot have WWWLL and LWWWL.
Total combinations = 26-2 = 24

Comment: I don't think it helps in this case, but in some similar situations it can be very helpful to *pretend* that the games go on to the end.

Comment: IMO, if you can solve a question more than one way, then do it. If you get the same answer both times, you can be more confident that your answer is correct. If you get a different answer with each approach, then you have the opportunity to double-check your assumptions and work.

Comment: @Code-Guru What does IMO mean?

Comment: IMO = In my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us solve a more general problem. Imagine we have a series between two teams, A and B. Team A wins a game with probability $p$, and we make the independence assumption of the OP. Let us suppose that the first team to win $w$ games wins the series.  Let $X$ be the number of games. Then $w\le X\le 2w-1$. Yours is the case $w=3$.

For any $k$ in this interval, we find the probability that $X=k$. In order for the series to have length exactly $k$, one of the teams has to have won $w-1$ of the first $k-1$ games, and has to win the last game.

The probability that A wins the series in $k$ games is therefore 
$$\binom{k-1}{w-1}p^{w-1}(1-p)^{w-k}p=\binom{k-1}{w-1}p^w(1-p)^{k-w},$$
and the probability that B wins the series  in $k$ games is 
$$\binom{k-1}{w-1}(1-p)^wp^{k-w}.$$
The events A wins the series in $k$ games and B wins the series in $k$ games are disjoint, so to find $\Pr(X=k)$ we add the two expressions above.

**Remark:** A distribution closely related to the above calculations is the *negative binomial*. For details, Wikipedia has a discussion, as do many introductory probability books.

For the case $w=3$, we don't need all this machinery, and can simply draw a tree.

Let $p=0.59$. We have $\Pr(X=3)=p^3+(1-p)^3$. For $k=4$, we get $3p^3(1-p)+3(1-p)^3p$. For $k=5$ we get $6p^3(1-p)^2+6(1-p)^3p^2$. All these expressions can be simplified somewhat.

Comment: +1 For a great explanation for applying the binomial distribution.

Comment: "In order for the series to have length exactly 3, one of the teams has to have won 2 of the first 2 games and has to win the last game." In other words, one team won the first three games, so the series is over.

Comment: I don't see why $k=6$ is mentioned, that can never happen. I would be careful about trying to guess general rules from the "win $3$" case. Best of $7$ gets more complicated, but the general analysis in my answer holds. Your addition did not address the probabilities. We are only interested in situations where the **series** is won in $3$, $4$, $5$.

Comment: @user1527227: About your first comment, sure it is true. The series lasts $3$ games precisely if it is a "sweep."  So yes, one team has to win the first two and win the third. Looks like a funny way of viewing things, but "series lasts exactly $4$" and "series lasts exactly $5$" falls under the same pattern. Perhaps I will add a remark at the end.